# Rake aborted: Don't know how to migrate after rails install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm trying to go from a newly installed version of rails. To creating a project and migrating the database based off of the model that I scaffolded using rails. And I'm running into a Don't know how to build task 'db::migrate' error.

Commands I ran..

Removing all gems:
`for i in 'gem list --no-versions'; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done`

Installing rails and creating new project
`sudo gem install rails`
`rails new test-api`
`rails generate controller user index`
`rails generate model user name:string`

So that is my setup..

Then I did the method to migrate my database:
`rake db::migrate`

And here was my output:

```
rake db::migrate
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db::migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:40:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Had I just refreshed my page on my server I would have found this:

[image]

Which gave me the answer to just run this command:

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```